# How to show total products number category wise?

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I need a little help. I want to show how many products are published category wise. Here I am using this code to show how many products published by seller.

```
{{ \App\Product::where('published', 1)->where('added_by', 'seller')->get()->count() }}
```

Please help me regarding this issue. I had share my category and product DB table with Screenshot.

Category DB
[image: categories]

Product DB
[image: products]

Here is categorycontroller

```
    public function index(Request $request)

{

    $sort_search =null;

    $categories = Category::orderBy('order_level', 'desc');

    if ($request->has('search')){

        $sort_search = $request->search;

        $categories = $categories->where('name', 'like', '%'.$sort_search.'%');

    }

    $categories = $categories->paginate(15);

    return view('backend.product.categories.index', compact('categories', 'sort_search', products));

}
```

Here is ProductController

```
 public function admin_products(Request $request)

{

    //CoreComponentRepository::instantiateShopRepository();



    $type = 'In House';

    $col_name = null;

    $query = null;

    $sort_search = null;



    $products = Product::where('added_by', 'admin');



    if ($request->type != null){

        $var = explode(",", $request->type);

        $col_name = $var[0];

        $query = $var[1];

        $products = $products->orderBy($col_name, $query);

        $sort_type = $request->type;

    }

    if ($request->search != null){

        $products = $products

                    ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');

        $sort_search = $request->search;

    }



    $products = $products->where('digital', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);



    return view('backend.product.products.index', compact('products','type', 'col_name', 'query', 'sort_search'));

}



/**

 * Display a listing of the resource.

 *

 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

 */

public function seller_products(Request $request)

{

    $col_name = null;

    $query = null;

    $seller_id = null;

    $sort_search = null;

    $products = Product::where('added_by', 'seller');

    if ($request->has('user_id') && $request->user_id != null) {

        $products = $products->where('user_id', $request->user_id);

        $seller_id = $request->user_id;

    }

    if ($request->search != null){

        $products = $products

                    ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');

        $sort_search = $request->search;

    }

    if ($request->type != null){

        $var = explode(",", $request->type);

        $col_name = $var[0];

        $query = $var[1];

        $products = $products->orderBy($col_name, $query);

        $sort_type = $request->type;

    }



    $products = $products->where('digital', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);

    $type = 'Seller';



    return view('backend.product.products.index', compact('products','type', 'col_name', 'query', 'seller_id', 'sort_search'));

}



public function all_products(Request $request)

{

    $col_name = null;

    $query = null;

    $seller_id = null;

    $sort_search = null;

    $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

    if ($request->has('user_id') && $request->user_id != null) {

        $products = $products->where('user_id', $request->user_id);

        $seller_id = $request->user_id;

    }

    if ($request->search != null){

        $products = $products

                    ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');

        $sort_search = $request->search;

    }

    if ($request->type != null){

        $var = explode(",", $request->type);

        $col_name = $var[0];

        $query = $var[1];

        $products = $products->orderBy($col_name, $query);

        $sort_type = $request->type;

    }



    $products = $products->paginate(15);

    $type = 'All';



    return view('backend.product.products.index', compact('products','type', 'col_name', 'query', 'seller_id', 'sort_search'));

}
```

**Here is Category Model**

```
    class Category extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('alphabetical', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->orderBy('name', 'asc');
        });
    }

    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }

    public function subSubCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubSubCategory::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Here is Product Model**

```
    class Product extends Model

{

//    protected $fillable = ['current_stock', 'variations', 'num_of_sale'];

    protected $fillable = ['variations', 'num_of_sale'];



    protected static function boot()

    {

        parent::boot();



        static::addGlobalScope('published', function (Builder $builder) {

            $builder->where('published', 1);

        });

    }



    public function user()

    {

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

    }



    public function category()

    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);

    }



    public function brand()

    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);

    }



    public function stocks()

    {

        return $this->hasMany(ProductStock::class);

    }



    public function wishlists() {

        return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class);

    }



    public function taxes() {

        return $this->hasMany(ProductTax::class);

    }



    public function flash_deal_product() {

        return $this->hasOne(FlashDealProduct::class);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please put the actual code in your question as text not in screenshots (I am not going to a 3rd party page just to have all the information on your question).

Comment: I updated that. Have a look , Please.

Comment: Have you defined the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) between models?

Comment: Yes!! it already defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `groupBy()` on the `category_id` column. to give you and idea, you could write something like:

```
 {{ \App\Product::selectRaw('category_id', 'count(*)')->where('published', 1)->where('added_by', 'seller')->groupBy('category_id')->get() }}
```

Comment: Can you explain? It's not working. Actually I am giving this in frontpage.

Comment: it gives you a collection of category ids with their count. you will need to use a foreach loop to extract them.